# Link gives me a 404 Page not found instead of loading a PHP file

Tags: php, wordpress

Whenever I try to link a PHP script, it doesn't work, and instead gives me the 404 Page not found error. Only the pages created on WordPress will be linkable, and it is possible for me to add a PHP model to the WordPress page, but I feel like there's a way to just load a PHP file without having to create another WordPress page.

I am not sure if I just don't put the PHP files in the correct folder on my server, my PHP files that I am trying to load are currently in my child-theme folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

slightly unclear, but of what i can grasp of your situation, you are attempting to directly execute php on a wordpress site (that's a serious security flaw). you are most likely using rewrite rules to have pretty urls, if that is the case (your links do not have a .php extension), then your direct links with the php extension get cought up in the rewrite rules and attempt to end up... well most likely nowhere, hence the 404. You can disable rewrite rules in your wordpress config, but i would not advise that. as anyhow it will lead to poor include management and bad general usage of the wordpress core. The proper way is really to make your template and then a page that uses it.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer! Can you explain why it's a serious security flaw to "directly execute php on a wordpress site"?

Comment: well in general, going around the standard wordpress integration forces YOU to deal with all the security that wordpress handles for you. There is a way to do that correctly, its just much less likely to end well than use standard wordpress